# Email Communication integration Web Application

Tags: php, web-applications, email

I am working on an web application. Where I need to create a new email id for every ticket generated in my system. Like if my ticket number is WSA111 then an email id should be created like WSA111.myapp@mydomain.com and if any one reply on this email should automatically come into my web application corresponding to that ticket only. This email id creation and data retrieval should happen automatically.

I want your help to know how can I accomplish this.

Regards,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

There are several steps you need to go through to accomplish this. You haven't provided enough detail, or any example code, for me to give you more specific help, but this is the gist of what you need to do.

1. On your mail server create a pipe that sends any email to your ticket system address  to a php script you create. (Google send-or-pipe-an-email-to-a-php-scrip)
2. The script should receive the email and parse the ticket number looking for the string "WSA" in the address. (see http://blog.hardkap.com/index.php/posts/00055/PHP-script-to-handle-incoming-mails-using-pipes)
3. The script should search the ticket system for a ticket number matching the parsed data. If found, add the email details to your ticket system for the existing ticket and prepare and send any response to that email you want it to send.
4. If not found, the script should create a new ticket and send a response to the users from the address specific to that ticket. When the user replies, step 1, above will fire.

This should get you going. Come back to me after you have created the process above and let me know if you have any issues or questions.